# Why does github copilot autosuggesions are not autofilled in .md files?

Tags: github, github-copilot

I am trying to create github README in .md file, i can see github actions suggestions but when i try to auto fill by tab, it doesn't work. the same does work files having .js extension

I dont want to copy past by hitting CTRL+ enter and paste from suggestions

Comment: Good question. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I started a discussion in there forum: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/10203

Answer (score 0):

Disable Markdown All in One, and it will work or to keep markdown all in one follow these steps:

- update your keybindings.json (`Ctrl+Shift+p`)
- find Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)) by adding the following:

  [
  {
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "markdown.extension.onTabKey",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !inlineSuggestionVisible && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus && !hasOtherSuggestions && !hasSnippetCompletions && !inSnippetMode && !suggestWidgetVisible && editorLangId == 'markdown'"
  },
  {
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "-markdown.extension.onTabKey",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus && !hasOtherSuggestions && !hasSnippetCompletions && !inSnippetMode && !suggestWidgetVisible && editorLangId == 'markdown'"
  }
  ]